# How to handle more than 1 unique index on error 1062?

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I have a table with 2 unique index fields: `email` and `doc`. I need to alert the user when a duplicate key insertion is detected. I can do it using:

```
...
catch(PDOException $e) {
    if($e->getCode() == 1062)
    ...
    }
```

But I don't know which indexes triggered this error. Is there a way to find out?

I found on Google that you can do it via the `getMessage()` function, but it appears that some versions of MySQL return something like `key 1`, while others return `name_of_key`, which makes this difficult to work with. Do I need to do a select before inserting? It looks ugly.

Thanks.

Comment: not uncommon to check with a select (and giving appropriate feedback) before doing an insert.

Comment: Select in the catch that way your not hitting the db again unless there is a failure

Comment: easiest way is to check the field is exist or not first.

Comment: Charlie what did u mean? i don't understand

Comment: @Dagon: it's actually not common, since it's a race condition prone

Comment: I mean 'Check with a select before insert'.

Comment: @zerkms did u know some way to do it without make select? i thought that maybe i could verifie the key as number and key as name in duplicate key error maybe it could do the trick.

Comment: @user2379521: I have never seen a server to return a number instead of a name

Comment: @Charlie: what if there was another row inserted right after your check and before your insert? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software

Comment: @zerkms Mysql installed on my localhost returns :  #1062 - Duplicate entry '5' for key 1

Comment: @zerkms and the MySQL Of my remote server returns the name of key instead '1'

Comment: what does the table schema look like. show create table fred

Comment: @user2379521: what versions are they? And, yep, what are the exact table schemes for both servers?

Comment: My localhost is 5.0.51b-community-nt-log and my remote server is 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6

Comment: @user2379521: do unique keys on both servers have names?

Comment: @zerkms yes, i created it like: ,unique index name_here (field)

Comment: @user2379521: what if you check it with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: @zerkms CREATE TABLE `test3` (
`cod` int(11) default NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `testando` (`cod`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @zerkms how u can see the name of this key is 'testando' but in duplicate key erro returns key 1 on my localhost and on remote server returns 'testando'

Comment: @user2379521: my the only idea is that it's 5.0 expected behaviour

Comment: @zerkms me too, well i'll do two verified then it could returns the 'number of key' or 'name of key'.. i think it can do the trick.

Comment: @zerkms i not like the idea of do a select before insert.

Comment: @user2379521: because it wouldn't solve the issue :-)

Comment: @user2379521, do select after insert : )

Comment: @zerkms last couple of sites i signed up for where clearly looking up my selected user name to check it was available; i then went on to fill in the rest of the form. Do you think they stored it temporarily in the db in case someone else tried the same username? then they would also have to purge them in case i walked away with out completing the form

Comment: @Dagon: select before insert there is done just for convenience, but you still need to have a handler to handle the unique index violation properly, in case if 2 people try to register simultaneously. I won't wonder if someone locks the username temporarily (after you put the name to a correspondent field but haven't submitted it yet, just as a hold) though, but for that you need a proper thread-safe storage for which you presumably also need to handle a unique constraint violation :-)

Comment: i think i would go for the low volume lazy approach and check, not lock, and then have an error and make them do it all again, if someone happened to of chosen the same name post check, pre submit. On most sites i would expect very infrequent clashes

Comment: Use InnoDB and "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE".  This will lock the presence, or non-presence of the key.  If it doesn't exist there won't be a race.  If using MyISAM use LOCK TABLE to lock the table so that only one thread can access it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this cross-version, you really need to place a SELECT before the INSERT.
You can safely do a select before the insert without a race, as long as you create the appropriate locks.

For best performance, use InnoDB and "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" because it features row-level locking.  The SELECT ... FOR UPDATE will lock the row if it is present or a "gap" for the row if it is not.  Don't use SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE because that will create read locks which will have to be upgraded to write locks, and a deadlock could happen.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

If using MyISAM use LOCK TABLE to lock the table so that only one thread can access it.
 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/lock-tables.html